# Is it possible to change a Trenitalia unused regional ticket after the time of departure of the train?

Tags: trains, public-transport, tickets, italy, trenitalia

When you buy a Trenitalia online regional ticket, I have notice that you are allowed to ask for a change of the train. However, the conditions under which you can ask for such a change are not clear to me.

Let's suppose you have some problem, for instance a delay on the flight, so you can't board the train at the departure time stated on the ticket. Is it still possible to ask for a change of the train online?

What about an unused regional ticket that has already been changed: is it possible to ask for another change?

More generally, under which conditions you are allowed to ask for a change on your unused online regional tickets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [English Trenitalia page](http://www.trenitalia.com/tcom-en/Purchase/Regional-online-ticket-and-passes) (the page specifically refers to regional electronic tickets):

> When and where can I change my ticket?
>
> You can change the date of your trip once only, up to the time of 23-59 on the day prior to the date indicated on your ticket, at:
>
> [...]
>
> You will be given a memorandum with the new date of the trip, that must be shown together with the original ticket.

So no, you can't change a ticket which already has been changed, and no, you can't change a ticket after departure of the train (I just assume here that the date indicated on the ticket (as in the quote) is the departure date of the train you have the ticket for).

It seems that apart from the above there are no extra restrictions on when a ticket change is possible.